# Is it possible to use parallel processing in forward stepwise regression?

Tags: python, optimization, machine-learning, regression

I have a list of values l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd',...,'aa', 'ab',... ,'zzzzz'] 
each string in the list above has an associated value with it. For instance 'a' = 1, 'b' = 0.8, 'zz' = 1.3. This list is huge. I have a function called summer that takes in a list and sums the values up. 
I have another list that has values m = ['a','b','c']. I am using forward stepwise regression to sequentially add elements from l into m and am finding the list of n values that maximizes summer. For instance I may just want a maximum of two numbers from l that combined with m produce the highest value in summer. I have implemented this in python but it is very slow. I was wondering if it is possible to use parallel processing with this forward stepwise regression. I

Comment: _"each string in the list above has an associated value with it"_ - Sounds like you want a dictionary not a list.

Comment: I could use a dictionary but I thought using a list would be fine because I need to test each element individually and then add combinations together

Comment: The same can be done with a dictionary.

Comment: Wouldn't the elements need to be pulled out of the dictionary to be sequentially added in the forward regression? How much time would this save? If it just shaves off a couple mins its not a huge expense to me. I was just looking for any ideas for a massive time saver with stepwise regression and thought parallel processing might be ok to use

Comment: I'm pretty sure that dict would be faster. By how much though, I'm not sure. all you would really need in your function though is `sum(dictOfValues.values())`. I really think that would be the fastest way of doing what your trying to accomplish, as dict was made for this.

Comment: So the thing is that the values per item in the list are computed in a function. So I take the value from the list and add the list to the function and the function tells me the value. I don't have the values in one separate list